# Silhouette value of each cluster using clustMixType

Tags: r

Using the `clustMixType` package I'm trying to get the silhouette values of the following dataset using the example in page 13 here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clustMixType/clustMixType.pdf

```
n   <- 10
prb <- 0.99
muk <- 2.5

x1 <- sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(prb, 1-prb))
x1 <- c(x1, sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-prb, prb)))
x1 <- as.factor(x1)

x2 <- sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(prb, 1-prb))
x2 <- c(x2, sample(c("A","B"), 2*n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-prb, prb)))
x2 <- as.factor(x2)

x3 <- c(rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk), rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk))
x4 <- c(rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk), rnorm(n, mean = -muk), rnorm(n, mean = muk))

x <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

This seems to work to obtain the silhouette value for several k number of clusters:

```
library(clustMixType)
Essil <- numeric(5)
for(i in 2:6){
  kpres <- kproto(x, k = i,na.rm=FALSE )
  val_sil<-validation_kproto(method = "silhouette", object=kpres)
  Essil[i] <- val_sil
}
plot(1:6, Essil, type = "b", ylab = "Silhouette", xlab = "Number of clusters")
Essil
```

Therefore as shown in the plot, the best number of clusters would be 4.

[image]

But `validation_kproto` gives the ***mean*** silhouette value for each k, perhaps 4 clusters gives best mean silhouette but with some of the clusters having a silhouette lower than 0.5.
Perhaps 5 clusters would be a better solution.

Therefore it would be important to know the silhouette value **of each cluster**, would that be possible?

I've tried setting `kp_obj='all'` but does not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, the `validation_kproto` function only outputs the silhouette index for the entire cluster partition. It is currently not possible to get the indices per cluster.

Possible alternative in the current state: use `val <- validation_kproto(data = x, k = 2:6, kp_obj = "all")` (instead of `for(i in 2:6){...}`) and get all examined kproto-objects where you can compare the within cluster distances (`val$kp_obj$withinss`).

Many greetings Rabea

[clustmixtype](/questions/tagged/clustmixtype)